# Is it possible to dynamicaly control blender loop cuts within Three.JS

Tags: javascript, three.js, blender-2.67

I am looking to control a blender created mesh that contains loop cuts. The example is a cube that contains loop cuts then twisted to form a thread.

Blender Example: [Blender cube with loop cuts](https://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=blender%20software%20%2B%20twist&&view=detail&mid=FFF5056088461D838B2DFFF5056088461D838B2D&&FORM=VDRVRV)

Is it possible to export the mesh and control the twist dynamically within Three.JS.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use morph target animation for this use case. In Blender they are called [Shape Keys](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/shape_keys/index.html). You can then export to `glTF` and import via `THREE.GLTFLoader`. The twist can be controlled by modulating [Mesh.morphTargetInfluences](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/objects/Mesh.morphTargetInfluences). It's even possible to animate a transition from on state of the mesh to another.

Note that loop cuts do not exist as an entity if you export a mesh from Blender to e.g. `glTF`. It is of course possible to change the geometry in `three.js` as you like but using morph targets seems the easier approach. Especially for a beginner in `three.js` or computer graphics in general.

`three.js R113`

Comment: Many thanks Mugen87 for the information. I will research Morph Targets to see how they work in blender as shape keys. That has saved me many hours trying to figure out how to export and manipulate loop cuts in ThreeJS.
Many Many Thanks.